# Покажите пример кода, где нарушение SRP приводило бы к багам

Tags: solid

Принцип единственной ответственности говорит о том, что у класса должна быть только одна обязанность, и что если нарушить этот принцип и намешать много всего в один класс, то у него будет больше чем одна причина для изменений и в результате этих изменений мы можем изменяя одну часть затрагивать другую часть класса тем самым создавая баги. Я бы хотел увидеть пример кода где такое происходит когда меняя одно мы при этом не намеренно вызываем изменения в другой части класса.

Comment: Вы книгу Роберта Мартина почитайте, там всё есть. Чистая Архитектура, емнип.

Comment: SRP гораздо больше про управление сложностью. Про то чтобы не городить монолит в котором все зависит от всего. Про расчленение кода на простые и заменяемые "модули" с соответствующими лаконичными API между ними и инкапсуляцией логики внутри.